# How to find a table's methatable

Tags: lua

Is there a test ( or a magical way) to find out if a table you encounter in a script has a metatable somewhere else in this script or other modules that are being required?? That is without scouring the entire code.

Comment: Is `getmetatable` what you are looking for?

Answer (score 4):

if you want to know for sure:

```
if getmetatable(some_table) ~= nil then
  print "It has a metatable"
else
  print "It doesn't have a metatable"
end
```

This detects a metatable even if it has been "hidden" by setting `__metatable = false`. In case you want to respect this and consider a "hidden" metatable as no metatable at all, you have to also check for `false` (or just write `if getmetatable(some_table) then...`)

(Thanks Egor Skriptunoff for pointing that out!)

Comment: `some_table = setmetatable({}, {__metatable=false})`

Comment: @EgorSkriptunoff: Test against `nil` to ensure that there is no metatable.

Answer (score 2):

You will need to read the documentation or source code if you want information on the contents of a metatable.

A table's metatable can be locked by defining `__metatable` at which point the `getmetatable` could almost any value that the programmer wanted to return, it can not be set to `nil`.

[Lua-Users Metatable Events](http://lua-users.org/wiki/MetatableEvents)

> __metatable - Hide the metatable. When "getmetatable( myTable )" is called, if the metatable for myTable has a __metatable key, the value of that key is returned instead of the actual metatable.

There is no guarantee method to that can tell you the contents of a given table's metatable.

edited: to cover `nil` as a value not possible when a metatable is set, as stated by Nicol Bolas

Comment: This is not entirely true. If a metatable has the `__metatable` field set, then it can't be set to `nil`. Therefore `getmetatable` will return something *other* than `nil`. It will only ever return `nil` if there is no metatable set at all. So, while you can hide the metatable *itself*, you can't hide the fact that you have set one.